# Store and access functions inside and from dictionary

Tags: swift, function, dictionary

I'd like to store and access functions inside a dictionary. What type should I provide? `Any` renders the function unusable:

```
func updateCalculations(_ function: String) {

    let functions : [String : Any] = ["calculateFunction1": CurrentDifferenceFunctions().calculateFunction1(), 
                                      "calculateFunction2": CurrentDifferenceFunctions().calculateFunction2()]

    let funcDict = functions[function]
    guard let function = funcDict else { return }

    func beginCalculations() {
        function() //Expression of type 'Any' is unused
    }


}
```

EDIT: This works!

```
let functions : [String : () -> Void] = ["calculateFunction1": CurrentDifferenceFunctions().calculateFunction1, 
                                         "calculateFunction2": CurrentDifferenceFunctions().calculateFunction2]
```

Comment: Function types are spelt as `(Arg1Type, Arg2Type) -> ReturnType` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94

Comment: What if my function doesn't take any argument and doesn't return anything?

Comment: Then it has no args, and has a return type of `Void`: `() -> Void`

Comment: Thanks Alexander, it's exactly the case + I forgot the `()` when calling the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CurrentDifferenceFunctions {

    func calculateFunction() {
        print("Hello World")
    }
}

let function = CurrentDifferenceFunctions().calculateFunction
var functions: [String: () -> Void] = ["calculateFunction": function]
functions["calculateFunction"]?()
```

Prints:

> Hello World

Comment: Thanks a lot! My function doesn't take any argument and doesn't return anything, who can i check it's type then?

Comment: Works great thanks! But I need to use `let funcDict = functions[function]
guard let function = funcDict else { return }` so I can access any function I need with an argument (the dictionary actually have a lot of functions inside)

Comment: @Martin33000 I think you should provide more information in your original question. Because I don't fully understand

Comment: Yes I'm sorry it wasn't so clear, I updated the question

Comment: Okay it works with the argument and the `() -> Void` type! `function` needed `function()`. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you're calling `calculateFunction` during the assignment into the dictionary. Here's how I would rewrite it:

```
func updateCalculations(_ function: String) {
    let cdf = CurrentDifferenceFunctions()
    // create dictionary, type is [String: ()->()] 
    // - the compiler figures that out by inference
    let functions = [
        "calculateFunction1": cdf.calculateFunction1,
        "calculateFunction2": cdf.calculateFunction2
    ]

    // get the named function from the dictionary
    guard let fun = functions[function] else {
        return
    }

    // call it
    fun()
}
```

Comment: What about my `functions[function]` argument to select the right function in the dictionary?

Comment: That doesn't even compile, given the code you've shown us.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it common to let the compiler figure the dict type out by itself?

Comment: Absolutely, relying on inference is very common.